# Как сделать направление через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Как сделать направление через .htaccess? У меня такой код который направляет `http://site/andrey` на `http://site/profile.php?user_url=andrey`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user_url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?user_url=$1
```

А как направлять так `http://site/andrey` на `http://site/profile.php?user_url=andrey` и плюс `http://site/andrey?article=123` на `http://site/article.php?article=123`

Comment: что касается второго вопроса по выдиранию значения из %{QUERY_STRING} тут надо подумать...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала остановите выполнение команды в первых правилах добавив [L] в конец правил.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user_url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?user_url=$1 [L]
```

**update**

Вместо двух одинаковых правил проще написать одно

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile.php?user_url=$1 [L]
```

**update**

А более правильно будет перенаправлять с адреса без слеша в конце, на адрес со слешем, автоматически

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?user_url=$1 [L]
```

При этом, поисковая система забудет про дубль страницы `http://site/andrey` и будет всегда обращаться на `http://site/andrey/`

**update**

Я думаю тут надо что то типа [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383669/htaccess-rewriterule-page-with-query-string) писать, этой техникой я не особо владею, ибо она не особо кошерная, проще урл в php сменить на нормальный ЧПУ и потом его уже по человечески разбирать.

**update**

Это работает в лоб, но нужно еще вынести в переменную значение 123

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^article=123$
RewriteRule ^andrey$ /article.php?article=123 [R=301,L]
```

**update**

Готово

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^article=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^andrey$ /article.php?article=%0 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо а как добавить конце `?article=123`

Comment: сейчас проведу эксперимент, подождите 20 мин.

Comment: Спасибо от души

Comment: получилось применить?

Comment: нет чета не получается а как вынести в переменную значение `andrey` :(

Comment: так это уже другой вопрос вообще то) на этот вопрос я ответил. а про вынос в переменную слова andrey, отдельно надо обсуждать, ибо у вас не совсем правильная какая то структура.

Comment: просто так нельзя поставить правило для первого раздела, ибо у вас все остальное не будет работать. вам бы перед словом andrey добавить префикс в виде каталога, например так /user/andrey, тогда другие части сайта у вас будут правильно работать

Comment: Аааа спасибо вам

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^article=([0-9]+)$`
`RewriteRule ^user/([-a-zA-Z]+)/$ /article.php?article=%0&user=$1 [L]
` Вам надо что то типа такого использовать, чтобы знать на какой скрипт отправлять значения с именем юзера, и `article.php` тут не совсем правильно.